# Spinning of the Earth

Tags: quantum-spin, earth

I was just wondering What would happen if the earth spins the other way around purely interms of Physics ?

Comment: The sun would rise in the west. The solar day would be shorter than a sidereal day, instead of longer as it is now

Comment: Nothing supremely interesting

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29235/2451

Comment: Hurricanes would rotate the other way around, but basically what Jim said.

Answer (score 0):

The tides would be shorter, as the speed of the moon relative to the earths surface would change. Currently the tides change from furthest out to in every 6hrs and 12mins. This is due to the fact that the earth rotates once every 24 hours, and the tide changes every time the moon gets 1 quater of the way around the earth. 24/4 = 6 hours, plus 12 minutes because the moon has moved a little further. If the rotation of earth was reversed, the moon would go the other way (relatively speaking) so the 12 minutes would be subtracted, so the tides would take 5hrs and 48mins instead

Comment: Hi stanley, can you please elaborate on your answer and provide some reasoning why?  As it stands now your answer is better suited as a comment.

Comment: Ok ive done a bit more now, explanation